# J2ME: How to make a call?

Tags: java, java-me, midp

Let's suppose i have created a text box with a phone number in it prefilled. How do i make a call when a button Call is clicked. The call should be for the number specified in the text  box.

How to make a call programatically for the specified number in J2ME?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code.

```
 private void call(String number) {
    try {
    platformRequest("tel:" + number);
    } catch (ConnectionNotFoundException ex) {
    // TODO: Exception handling
    }
    }
```